# How to append data to an existing .mat file without loading the existing data from that mat file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, mat, large-data-volumes, large-data

I have a very huge chunk of data say about 3GB. When I try to load it and save it in a mat file, my laptop hangs as I have only 4GB RAM. Now I figured if I can divide my original data in smaller chunks and do whatever processing i need to do and save it into mat file in steps, it will not take much of RAM. 
But I couldn't find a way to append new data into the existing mat file without loading the existing data in it (which would fail the purpose).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `matfile`: [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html)

> `m = matfile(filename)` creates a MAT-file object, m, connected to the
>   MAT-file named filename. The object allows you to access and change
>   variables directly in a MAT-file, without having to load the variables
>   into memory.
>
> The partial loading and saving that the matfile function provides
>   requires less memory than the load and save commands, which always
>   operate on entire variables.